# VueJS / ExpressJS (Backend) - Getting data from an API

Tags: express, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm learning VueJS / Express and I'm trying to display data from an external API onto my page. I'm using Express as the API Calls require headers + I believe its safer to keep it separate from Vue.

Here is my Express

```
app.get('/summoner', function(request, response) {
  axios.get('https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/XXXXXXXX', {headers: headers})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
})
```

Here is my Vue code:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'summoner',
  data () {
    return {
      summoner: [],
      errors: []
    }
  },      
  created () {
    console.log('Created')
    axios.get('/api/summoner')
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Hit me')
        this.summoner = response.data
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
        console.log(e)
      })
  }
}
```

The console.log(response.data) is showing me the object I expect which is:

```
{ id: XXXXXXXX,
  accountId: XXXXXXXX,
  name: 'XXXXXXXX',
  profileIconId: XXXXXXXX,
  revisionDate: XXXXXXXX,
  summonerLevel: XXXXXXXX }
```

The console.log('Hit Me') is never fired
The console.log('Created') is fired on page load.

Nothing I seem to try allows me to display any of the object using Vue e.g:

```
{{ summoner.id }}
```

Just to add, I have configured a proxy in webpack which forwards the below requests to Express. As far as I can tell, this is working as each time I refresh the page, I see the ExpressJS console.log(response.data) fire

Could anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: Where is your `response.send` in express part? http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res

Comment: I added res.send(response.data) this still didnt seem to display the data or log the console.log('hit me') statement. Neither did using res.json([response.data]), although this did allow me to load my object in Chrome when visiting /api/summoner

Comment: So adding this to my Vue axios call: this.summoner = response.data[0] finally displayed the data in the page. Does anyone know why I need to specify the 0? 'Hit Me' still isn't logged to the console however.

Answer (score 0):

In your express code you do not return the repsonse (which you also override in the axios response). Try changing it to

```
app.get('/summoner', function(request, res) { // <--- careful here is a change
  axios.get('https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/XXXXXXXX', {headers: headers})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
    return res.status(200).send(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    return res.status(400).send(error);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually resolved this by doing:

```
res.json([response.data])
```

In the ExpressJS side of things.

I also had to use `response.data[0]` within Vue.